# Problem while loading static files|| django

Tags: django

iam learning Django i have learned pretty much. I used static method to rendered css and other static files. But changes iam making to css which is in static files are not reflacting on webpage . i have to close all files and restart vscode again to see those changes. I have not added code because im not getting any error at all .

( example :: i have changed font size of all anchors . Normally it should be changes on webpage after saving and refreshing the page. but in this case font size is not changing. i have to close all files and reopen them and after starting the server again i can see those changes which i made to anchor tag. )

Any one who knows why because to see changes restart whole project will never be a good option. **thanks in Advance**

Comment: what do you mean by "use static method to render css", you mean using some code? and after you modify the css, do you try to reload the page in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of your code use `{% load static %}` and where ever you want to use the files from static folder use `{% static 'name of your file' %}`

Make sure you've not added your static folder in your base directory. In such case update your settings.py

`STATIC_URL = '/static/'`

`STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]`

`STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')`

you can use whichever name you like instead of assets

Comment: I have stored static file inside my app. and they are rightly linked with html. I have done all cofigurations in settings.py which you have commented. Moreover the changes which iam making to my css is showing on page when i restart the whole project but i want them to accur at the spot . ( example :: i have changed font size of all anchors . Normally it should be changes on webpage after saving and refreshing the page. but in this case font size is not changing. i have to close all files and reopen them and after starting the server again i can see those changes which i made to anchor tag.  )

Comment: every time you make changes in css try rerunning the server or hard refresh the page